# Can I elect for a deductible Traditional IRA contribution to be treated as non-deductible?

Tags: united-states, ira, contribution, form-8606

I made a $6k contribution to a traditional IRA in December 2010 for tax year 2010.  I filed my tax return and incorrectly listed the contribution as a Roth contribution.

Can I amend my tax return to correct the contribution to instead be a traditional IRA contribution AND specify that the contribution is a non-deductible contribution to my traditional IRA even  thought I qualify based on my AGI for it to be deductible?

Is form 8606 the place to make such an election if possible?

Comment: Why would you do that? You'll pay taxes twice on the same money.

Comment: No, a non-deductible contribution may be withdrawn tax-free, only its earnings are taxable.

Comment: So why not just leave it in Roth? What's the difference? Just trying to learn here:-)

Comment: 2010 is special, your Roth conversion can be treated as taxable spread out over 2011 and 2012.  Do not want deduction in 2010 to increase my taxes in 2011 and 2012 due to expected higher earnings in those years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in [IRS Publication 590](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p590.pdf) on page 17

```
When you file, you can even designate otherwise deductible
contributions as non deductible contributions.
```

On IRS Form 8606 you may enter the non deductible amount on line 1 of the form.

The [instructions](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8606.pdf) for [IRS Form 8606](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8606.pdf) state on page 5:

```
line 1 - refers to entering the amount on line 1
         "you chose to deduct on Form 1040".
```

Taking the deduction is optional if you qualify for the deduction.